# NDK build error in Android Studio for some C++ code

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am new to NDK, so I am getting an error while building the project below:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug'.
java.io.IOException: Failed to delete E:\startUpCode\OpenCvDemo\NDKTest\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stripDebugSymbol\debug\folders\2000\1f\main\lib\mips
```

This is my C++ code:

```
#include <com_nickworld_ndktest_NativeClass.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_nickworld_ndktest_NativeClass_getMessageFromJNI
    (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj){
return env->NewStringUTF("This is the message from JNI");
```

#### File *android.mk*

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_nickworld_ndktest_NativeClass.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
LOCAL_MODULE := MyLib

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

#### File *Application.mk*

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-16
```

#### File *MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("MyLibs");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView)).setText(NativeClass.getMessageFromJNI());
    }
}
```

How can I fix this error? Where am I doing a mistake?

Comment: did you try to make clean build?

Comment: Yes i did clean build already

Comment: You could consider updating your android studio to latest version if not, and invalidate caches and restart the studio.

Comment: i think i have updated to latest version only

Comment: Have you tried temporarily disabling your AV or any other background processes that might be monitoring file operations?

Comment: Please add your CMake.txt and app gradle file

Answer (score 4):

Try deleting `E:\startUpCode\OpenCvDemo\NDKTest\app\build\intermediates` manually. Then try building again.

Comment: So you get the same error even after deleting `build\intermediates`? Or are you unable to delete in manually. What about if you delete the entire `build` directory? Let me know if it's the same error or a different one.

Comment: not slove its giving this error now Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
> Process 'command 'C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: Ok. Run `ndk-build V=1` from your `E:\startUpCode\OpenCvDemo\NDKTest\app\src\main\jni` directory and check the output. It will tell you why it's failing. Share the output with us if you don't know how to resolve it after viewing the output. If that command doesn't work, try these commands from your `E:\startUpCode\OpenCvDemo\NDKTest` directory: `gradlew buildNative --info`, `gradlew buildNative --stacktrace`, `gradlew buildNative --debug`

Comment: how to run this

Comment: In Android Studio, click on the `Terminal` tab at the bottom of the window. If it's not there, then on the menu bar click `View > Tool Windows > Terminal`. Then run `gradlew buildNative -info`, or `cd app/src/main/jni` and then `ndk-build V=1`. Let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142292/discussion-between-martin-and-nikhil-sharma).

Answer (score 1):

I have already faced this problem and there isn't any issue in your code, so check out these points:

1. go to your project and check if it creates jnilibs or whatever you named it in your Gradle **NDK_LIBS_OUT**
2. check your **task ndkBuild** in your app Gradle file and its location
3. clean your project and build it again if it does not have created it yet

Answer (score 0):

I have also been facing the same problem regarding NDK in my project as I have imported downloaded project.

I was stuck for a week to solve the problem. Then I have created a new project and added library and all files to this new one project and  build the project.

And I successfully built my project.

Comment: I will try to new but i am not getting you i am getting this problem :(

Comment: this error is becoz your project not getting dependencies of your ndk libraries